# jquery dialog error : Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: jquery, dialog

I get an error message from my jquery dialog:

> Error: Expected identifier, string or number.

The error message points to the line with the `buttons: {`  declaration.  Any know what could cause the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html('<form id="myform" action=""><input type="checkbox" id="completeCheck" name="completeCheck" value="" />Completeness check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="viewUnofficial" value="Car" /> View unofficial status <br /><input type="checkbox" name="consist" value="" />Consistency<br /><input type="checkbox" name="otherData" value="" />Other checks<br /><input type="checkbox" name="keyCheck" value="" />Key check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="compareVersions" value="" />Compare versions<br /></form>').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Select data check',
    buttons: {
        "Submit Form": function () {
            $('form#myform').submit();
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

});
```

Comment: may be this would help,your declaration is not correct

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608244/changing-my-jquery-dialog-button-text-when-dialog-loads

Comment: IE7 gives this exact error when you have trailing commas in object literals.

Comment: but I don't have trailing commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working demo of your code** http://jsfiddle.net/ta7QY/

Feel free to play around with the demo; `$('div')` and I have also instantiated the dialog on click of a link. rest code as per below.

This will help, `:)`

**code**

```
$("#forgot").click(function(e){ 
    $dialog.dialog("open");
    e.preventDefault();
});


var $dialog = $('<div>')
    .html('<form id="myform" action=""><input type="checkbox" id="completeCheck" name="completeCheck" value="" />Completeness check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="viewUnofficial" value="Car" /> View unofficial status <br /><input type="checkbox" name="consist" value="" />Consistency<br /><input type="checkbox" name="otherData" value="" />Other checks<br /><input type="checkbox" name="keyCheck" value="" />Key check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="compareVersions" value="" />Compare versions<br /></form>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Select data check',
                buttons: {   
          "Submit Form": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
          "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    });
​
```

**Script**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css">

  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow, thanks!  So, then there isn't anything wrong with the code? I can add more code to see where the failure occurs.

Comment: @user840930 Glad it helped 1) `$('<div>')` instead of `$('<div></div>')` another way I did was calling dialog open and then preventDefault, anyhoo it should help, apart from that nothing else,  happy to help you out! thanx

Comment: I removed the </div> from mine and recieved an error message: Error Traced[line: 108] The element type "div" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</div>". so I'm not sure how representative the demo is